# How to use flatMap() after filter()

Tags: java, rx-java

I have this method which load entity from the Database and check for a certain condition if true then apply another operation on the entity

```
public Single<APIResponse> getDetails(String id) {
    return repository.getById(id)
            .filter(entity -> entity.getStatus()!= Status.FAILED)
            .flatMap(entity -> getDetails(entity, identity)
                    .map(response -> enrichResponseWithEntityData(response, entity))
            );
}
```

My IDE is giving compile time error:-

> Incompatible types. Required Single but 'flatMap' was
>   inferred to Maybe: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so
>   that Maybe conforms to Single

How can I `filter` then apply `flatMap` on a stream ?

Answer (score 0):

Your method getDetails() or/and enrichResponseWithEntityData() is returning Maybe and your stream was init with Single.

You can do 3 things:

1. use flatMapMaybe instead of flatMap
2. change return value of getDetails() or/and enrichResponseWithEntityData() to be Single
3. convert result of map() to Single by using toSingle() or toSingle(default)